# How do I create permutations of of each keys from dictionary?

Tags: python, graph, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

Say I have a dictionary of letters with assigned values:

```
  dictionary = {"l":"smias", "k":"swdw", 'm':'blala'}
```

how do i create permutations of keys without duplicates and return them as tuples like this?

```
  mytuple = ((l,k),(l,m),(k,m))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is combinations, not permutations. You can get either with [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

d = {"l":"smias", "k":"swdw", 'm':'blala'}

tuple(combinations(d, r=2))
# (('l', 'k'), ('l', 'm'), ('k', 'm'))
```

Or permutations:

```
from itertools import permutations

d = {"l":"smias", "k":"swdw", 'm':'blala'}

tuple(permutations(d, r=2))
# (('l', 'k'), ('l', 'm'), ('k', 'l'), ('k', 'm'), ('m', 'l'), ('m', 'k'))
```

Comment: how do i do it without itertools?

Comment: @AndreaR. You would write loops over the dictionary keys, but it will be slower. Unless this is homework, there's almost no reason not to use itertools — it's part of python.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this without using libraries.

```py
def combinations(lst, length, idx, cur, res):
    # length: length of each item in combinations
    if length == 0:
        res.append(tuple(cur))
        return
    for i in range(idx, len(lst)):
        combinations(lst, length - 1, i + 1, cur + [lst[i]], res)

res = []
dictionary = {"l":"smias", "k":"swdw", 'm':'blala'}
combinations(list(dictionary.keys()), 2, 0, [], res)
mytuple = tuple(res)
# (('l', 'k'), ('l', 'm'), ('k', 'm'))
```